# How to Call Stored Procedure in Apache Superset in (SQL_LAB) using Apache Superset(version 2.0.1)

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to call the stored procedure in apache superset using this Query:

```
SELECT  * FROM  OPENQUERY(
LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 
'EXECUTE myStoredProcedure param1, ''{{ ''.join(filter_values('myFilterColumn'))}}''
WITH RESULT SETS((    id int,
    [name] varchar(255),
    id_sent int,
    nbAddressSent int,
    nbOpeners int,
    nbClickers int    ))'
    )
```

can you please guide me on any other way to call the procedure?